# Can someone diagnose the problem with my Wine and Rose Weigelas please?

Tags: diagnosis

I have 6 and they all show the same stunted growth on some branches. The first photo shows the weigela that shows the most deformity. Thanks for any help!
[image: deformed or stunted branch ends. You can see some heathy red tips in the shrub next to it.]

Answer (score 1):

Brent, this looks normal for Weigela. I've pruned many of these in a few nurseries and they do this weird 'witches broom' when they are getting ready to flower.

This plant is showing a need for a balanced fertilizer.  If you want flowers then use a fertilizer that has N as the lowest number of N-P-K.  Use half of whatever fertilizer instructions come with the product.

Right after flowering you should 'head' prune these shrubs, before they start budding for flowers.  Do you have hand shears?  Doubled handed hedging shears?  This will keep them as shrubs.  Send a picture of the entire bunch so I can see how close they've been planted because...well, you could instead, prune them to be small trees, a grove of small trees?

Each shrub should be sheared into an upside down salad bowl.  This gets the proper form they want to have as a shrub and all leaves on the outside get plenty of light so they are able to do photosynthesis to the satisfaction of the plant.  Otherwise, the plant will get rid of leaves/branches that are unable to perform photosynthesis duties.

I can help with more detailed instructions on pruning, and this pruning can take place any time of the year if you don't care about flowering.  These 'shrubs' are best described as small trees, yes?  In case you want small trees, multi stemmed little grove of trees, you don't want to head them you want to THIN to prune.  Very big difference.  What were your plans for these shrubs?  These aren't the best 'domesticated' of shrubs. They are a bit on the weedy side and that is good depending on how much work you want to do.  Hardy, floriferous, lovely as small, patio trees.  As a 'grove' of trees.  A grove of trees all the same species, makes a 'room' in the landscape so easily.  One of my favorite inexpensive gimmicks to enhance a landscape so people are able to use it. A grove provides a 'ceiling', defines a floor and the trunks provide separation from you and the world.  Wonderful space to have in your landscape.  Humans will gravitate to a grove before a patio.

[Weigela pruning](https://plantcaretoday.com/growing-weigela-care.html)

There are a few things wrong with this article such as planting plants in the garden one never ever digs the hole deeper than the root ball.  The root ball should sit on undisturbed soil. No amendments whatsoever. Water is crucial for the first year.  A little fertilizer; Less is Best, More is Death and None is Dumb.

Weigela is grown as a large shrub, not so much a small tree which is what I am guessing you wanted in the first place.  Before you do anything just reiterate what you think it is you should do, want to do.  In case, I've made this more confusing. Grins.

Answer (score 1):

[image: 3 shrubs on each side]

Prune individually or as a hedge? I have a hedge trimmer and double handled pruners. The 2 on both ends are smaller, because they were replacements planted this Spring. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Prune each shrub individually.  You will be pruning so that they make a 'soft' hedge.  I'll try to send a picture of what I am talking about!